# official icon for Touch ID and Face ID

Tags: ios, macos, icons, touch-id, face-id

Does Apple provide icons for Touch ID and Face ID that can be used in Apps?

I cannot find them. Searched in:

- https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/system-icons/
- https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/authentication/
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication

The [Apple MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207054) site provides one, but I think it´s not allowed to use it.

How do you solve that in your code? Designing an own icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons for Touch ID and Face ID now can be found in SFSymbols.

Use the symbol names "touchid" (iOS 14.0+, macOS 11.0+) and "faceid" (iOS 13.0+, macOS 11.0+).

Answer (score 3):

No. Apple recommends (in the links you provided) that you refer to the technology by name. eg:

*Sign In with Face ID*

or

*Sign In with Touch ID*